# Flag the month of default - python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({
'customer_id': ['100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600'],
'Month1': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
'Month2': [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
'Month3': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
'Month4': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]})
```

This is showing a boolean value for when a customer defaults on a loan. The first month with 0 means the customer defaulted that month. I want an output that displays the month number the customer defaulted on the loan.
Output:

```
pd.DataFrame({
'customer_id': ['100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600'],
'Month1': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
'Month2': [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
'Month3': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
'Month4': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
'default_month': [3, 2, 3, 3, 4, np.nan]})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check whether all the 'Month' columns in a row are not 0, using [`all(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and [`ne(0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) and return `np.nan` which means that the person has not yet defaulted (i.e. your row 5).

Then using [`eq(0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html)and [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) you can check which is the first value of a row that equals to `0` and grab that column name.

```
import numpy as np

m = df.filter(like='Month')
df['default_month'] = np.where((m.ne(0)).all(1),np.nan,
                               m.eq(0).idxmax(1))
```

---

```
df
 
  customer_id  Month1  Month2  Month3  Month4 default_month
0         100       1       1       0       0        Month3
1         200       1       0       0       0        Month2
2         300       1       1       0       0        Month3
3         400       1       1       0       0        Month3
4         500       1       1       1       0        Month4
5         600       1       1       1       1           NaN
```

Comment: I thought of this too, but there is an edge case this misses. If we had [1,1,0,1,0] The default month is really month 3. Simply adding payments would yield a result of 4.

Comment: If the edge case never happens, this is computationally more efficient than my answer.

Comment: You are absolutely right, haven't thought of that. I have corrected it now and this updated answer should cover your point :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code to get your result:

first we need a list of months in reverse order. From your data, I just pulled them directly from the index.

```
months = list(df.columns[1:5])
months.reverse()
```

`months` is now `['Month4', 'Month3', 'Month2', 'Month1']`.

We iterate backwards so when we find an earlier month of default, it overwrites

```
for (i,m) in enumerate(months):
    mask = df[m] == 0 # Check for a default

    df.loc[mask,'default_month'] = len(months) - i
```

This returns the output you are looking for.